# Creates an Excel inventory from Cisco Show Version text files

Tags: python, beginner, excel

This has been written for network engineers to be able to create an Excel inventory of switch/router device info from a folder of 'Show version' .txt files.  I've put it here to help me learn about Python and how I could potentially improve my coding, so please, feel free to rip into this and criticise!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Title:      Show File Inventory Creation
Usage:      Creates an excel spreadsheet inventory from a folder containing 
            Cisco 'show version' text files.  This inventory contains the 
            hostname, model & serial number of each device, including switch 
            stacks, and embeds each text file in the spreadsheet.
Platform:   Windows
Warning:    Only works with .xls files, NOT with .xlsx files
            'show' files must be .txt files
Date:       06/01/2015
Version:    2.1
''' 

import os
import csv
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook, easyxf
import win32com.client as win32
import win32gui
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon

#Define global variables for excel spreadsheet workbook and worksheet, 
#and a 'visual demarcation' line
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Inventory',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
vis_demarc_line = '\n\n' + ('=' * 100)

#Function to parse show files and store data in csv format, takes the 
#directory path of the folder containing the show files as a parameter.
def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
    #Inform user of progress
    print (vis_demarc_line + 
    "\n\n\tRetrieving device data from your 'show' files..."
    )
    #open temporary text file to store device data, 'a' :- append
    inventorytxt = open('inventory.txt', 'a')
    #write header line to text file
    inventorytxt.write('Hostname' + ',' + 'Model' + ',' + 
        'Serial Number' + '\n'
        )
    #iterate through each file in the specified folder
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        #specify each show file in turn
        with open(os.path.join(path,filename),'r') as showfile:
            lines = showfile.readlines()
            #iterate through each line in the show file
            for line in lines:
                i = 1
                #specify hostname as preceding 'show version' command in file
                if '#sh ver' in line:
                    i += 1
                    if i <= 2:
                        hostname = line.split('#')[0]
                    else:
                        hostname = ' '
                    inventorytxt.write(hostname)
                elif '#show ver' in line:
                    i += 1
                    if i <= 2:
                        hostname = line.split('#')[0]
                    else:
                        hostname = ' '
                    inventorytxt.write(hostname)
                elif '#sho ver' in line:
                    i += 1
                    if i <= 2:
                        hostname = line.split('#')[0]
                    else:
                        hostname = ' '
                    inventorytxt.write(hostname)
                #specify model as last entry on line containing 'model number'
                if 'Model number' in line:
                    model = line.split()[-1]
                    inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')
                elif 'Model Number' in line:
                    model = line.split()[-1]
                    inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')
                #specify serial number as last entry on line containing 
                #'system serial number'
                if 'System serial number' in line:
                    serial = line.split()[-1]
                    inventorytxt.write(serial + '\n')
                elif 'System Serial Number' in line:
                    serial = line.split()[-1]
                    inventorytxt.write(serial + '\n')
    #close text file
    inventorytxt.close()
    #change temporary text file to temporary csv file
    os.rename('inventory.txt', 'inventory.csv')

#Function to write csv data to Excel spreadsheet
def csv_to_xls():
    #Inform user of progress
    print vis_demarc_line + '\n\n\tSaving device data to Excel spreadsheet...'
    #define spreadsheet cell styles
    header_style = xlwt.easyxf(
        'font: name Calibri, bold on, height 320, colour white;'
        'borders: left medium, right medium, top medium, bottom medium;'
        'alignment: horizontal centre, vertical centre;'
        'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour black;'
        )
    cell_style = xlwt.easyxf(
        'font: name Calibri, bold off, height 240;'
        'borders: left medium, right medium, top medium, bottom medium;'
        'alignment: horizontal centre, vertical centre;'
        )
    #change cell height and width
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < 4:
        sheet.col(i).width_mismatch = True
        sheet.col(i).width = 256*25
        i += 1
    while j < 200:
        sheet.row(j).height_mismatch = True
        sheet.row(j).height = 896
        j += 1
    #freeze header row
    sheet.set_panes_frozen(True)
    sheet.set_horz_split_pos(1)
    #open temporary csv file containing device data
    csvfile_reader = csv.reader(open('inventory.csv', 'rb'))
    #write csv data to Excel spreadsheet
    for rowx, row in enumerate(csvfile_reader):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value, cell_style)
    #re-write header row with new style
    sheet.write(0,0,'Hostname',header_style)
    sheet.write(0,1,'Model',header_style)
    sheet.write(0,2,'Serial Number',header_style)
    sheet.write(0,3,'Show File',header_style)
    #define inventory_dir as a global variable to be able to use outside 
    #of this function
    global inventory_dir
    inventory_dir = folder + 'Inventory\\'
    #create 'Inventory' folder if it doesn't already exist
    if not os.path.exists(inventory_dir):
        os.makedirs(inventory_dir)
    #save spreadsheet as temporary .xls file
    book.save(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls')

#Function to embed text files in spreadsheet
def embed_txt_files():
    #Inform user of progress
    print (vis_demarc_line + 
        "\n\n\tEmbedding your 'show' files into Excel spreadsheet..."
        )
    #open Excel
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    #Make Excel invisible to user
    xl.Visible = 0
    #open specific Excel workbook
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls')
    #define range as first 200 cells in column A
    range = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200")
    #iterate through cells
    for cell in range:
        #check to see if cell is not empty
        if cell.Value is not None:
            #specify 'show' text file based on hostname in cell in column A
            f = folder + str(cell.Value) + '.txt'
            #embed 'show' text file as OLEObject 
            ol = wb.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=f)
            #specify 'show' text file location as 3 cells to the right of 
            #cell in column A
            ol.Top = cell.GetOffset(0, 3).Top
            ol.Left = cell.GetOffset(0, 3).Left
    #save Excel workbook
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    #quit Excel
    xl.Quit()

#Function to allow user to rename the inventory spreadsheet
def rename_file():
    #ask user for the name of their inventory spreadsheet
    print vis_demarc_line
    #global xl_inventory_fname
    inventory_fname = raw_input(
        '\n\n\tWhat would you like to name your Inventory spreadsheet?\n\n\t:'
        )
    xl_inventory_fname = inventory_fname + '.xls'
    #test validity of users filename and rename temporary .xls file to 
    #user's desired name if an exception is not raised
    try:
        os.rename(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls', inventory_dir + 
            xl_inventory_fname
            )
        print (vis_demarc_line + 
        '\n\n\tYour Inventory spreadsheet has been created here: \n\n\t%s%s' 
        % (inventory_dir, xl_inventory_fname)
        )
        print vis_demarc_line + '\n\n'
    except:
        print vis_demarc_line + "\n\n\tSorry, that is an invalid filename."
        rename_file()

#Function to open browser window to enable user to choose folder containing 
#their 'show' text files
def main(): 
    desktop_pidl = shell.SHGetFolderLocation (
        0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, 0
        )
    pidl, display_name, image_list = shell.SHBrowseForFolder (
        win32gui.GetDesktopWindow (), desktop_pidl, 
        "Please choose the folder containing your 'show' files...", 
        0, None, None
        )
    #define folder as a global variable to be able to use outside of this 
    #function
    global folder
    #set folder to choice made in browser window
    folder = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList (pidl) + '\\'
    #call inventory_data_to_csvfile, csv_to_xls, embed_txt_files & 
    #rename_file functions
    inventory_data_to_csvfile(folder)
    csv_to_xls()
    embed_txt_files()
    rename_file()
    #delete temporary csv file
    os.remove('inventory.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

With

```
vis_demarc_line = '\n\n' + ('=' * 100)
```

Every time you use it is something like

```
print vis_demarc_line + '\n\n\t' + text
```

Except for one, which is just

```
print vis_demarc_line + '\n\n'
```

Since a trailing `\t` on its own is invisible, the simpler solution would be to write a funciton

```
def print_new_section(text):
    print('\n\n' + ('=' * 100) + '\n\n\t' + text)
```

You forgot a space here:

```
                                  ↓↓
sheet = book.add_sheet('Inventory',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

and similar for a few other function calls. You also don't have spaces after the comment hash (`#`). Other than that, the style is reasonable.

You use `with` to open `showfile` but you neglect to do so for `inventorytxt`. Don't; put it in a `with`.

Many of your comments aren't very useful. Consider

```
# Define global variables for excel spreadsheet workbook and worksheet
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Inventory', cell_overwrite_ok=True)
```

You know that from reading the code so you don't need to repeat it. An example of a good comment would be

```
# open temporary text file to store device data, 'a' :- append
with open('inventory.txt', 'a') as inventorytxt:
```

shortened to

```
# Temporary file for device data. 'a' :- append
with open('inventory.txt', 'a') as inventorytxt:
```

Note that this now only tells you the information that's not already in the code:

- It's temporary
- It holds device data
- 'a' means 'append'

If it doesn't give you *new* or clarifying information, it shouldn't be a comment.

This comment should be a docstring:

```
# Function to parse show files and store data in csv format, takes the 
# directory path of the folder containing the show files as a parameter.
def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
```

eg.

```
def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
    """
    Parse show files and store data in csv format.

    Takes the path for the folder containing the show files.
    """
```

There's no real reason for concatenation here:

```
inventorytxt.write('Hostname' + ',' + 'Model' + ',' + 
    'Serial Number' + '\n'
    )
```

Just use

```
inventorytxt.write('Hostname,Model,Serial Number\n')
```

This:

```
lines = showfile.readlines()
# iterate through each line in the show file
for line in lines:
```

should just be

```
for line in showfile:
```

since files are iterable. This will prevent the need to hold the whole file in memory. Also, prefer `list(showfile)` to `showfile.readlines`.

`i` is a good variable name if it is uniformly increasing by a fixed amount each iteration and its use it obvious. In this case, that isn't true. Something more descriptive like `count_sh_vers`. Note that that would imply reducing the count by 1 everywhere. However, the count is reset every loop iteration so the check `i <= 2` is always True. Remove the variable and check.

You repeat this three times:

```
i += 1
if i <= 1:
    hostname = line.split('# ')[0]
else:
    hostname = ' '
inventorytxt.write(hostname)
```

for three `if/elif`s. Just use `or` in the condition:

```
if '# sh ver' in line or '# sho ver' in line or '# show ver' in line:
```

Better might be using `re`:

```
if re.search(r'# sh(ow?)? ver', line):
```

You do

```
if 'Model number' in line:
    model = line.split()[-1]
    inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')
elif 'Model Number' in line:
    model = line.split()[-1]
    inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')
```

The second can never run since the condition is the same, but it doesn't matter as the body is the same too. Just remove the `elif`. The same thing happens again with `if 'System serial number' in line`. Are you sure you understand what `elif` does?

This simplifies the first function to

```
def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
    """
    Parse show files and store data in csv format.

    Takes the path for the folder containing the show files.
    """
    print_new_section("Retrieving device data from your 'show' files...")
    # Temporary file for device data. 'a' :- append
    with open('inventory.txt', 'a') as inventorytxt:
        inventorytxt.write('Hostname,Model,Serial Number\n')

        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as showfile:
                for line in showfile:
                    # Specify hostname as preceding 'show version' command in file
                    if re.search(r'# sh(ow?)? ver', line):
                        hostname = line.split('# ')[0]
                        inventorytxt.write(hostname)

                    # specify model as last entry on line containing 'model number'
                    if 'Model number' in line:
                        model = line.split()[-1]
                        inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')

                    # specify serial number as last entry on line containing 
                    # 'system serial number'
                    if 'System serial number' in line:
                        serial = line.split()[-1]
                        inventorytxt.write(serial + '\n')

    os.rename('inventory.txt', 'inventory.csv')
```

This is still too deeply nested to another function woulud be appropriate. This gives

```
def read_showfile_into(showfile, inventorytxt):
    for line in showfile:
        # Hostname precedes 'show version' command
        if re.search(r'# sh(ow?)? ver', line):
            hostname = line.split('# ')[0]
            inventorytxt.write(hostname)

        # Model is last entry
        if 'Model number' in line:
            model = line.split()[-1]
            inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')

        # Serial number is last entry
        if 'System serial number' in line:
            serial = line.split()[-1]
            inventorytxt.write(serial + '\n')

def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
    """
    Parse show files and store data in csv format.

    Takes the path for the folder containing the show files.
    """
    print_new_section("Retrieving device data from your 'show' files...")
    # Temporary file for device data. 'a' :- append
    with open('inventory.txt', 'a') as inventorytxt:
        inventorytxt.write('Hostname,Model,Serial Number\n')

        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as showfile:
                read_showfile_into(showfile, inventorytxt)

    os.rename('inventory.txt', 'inventory.csv')
```

In `csv_to_xls`, you do

```
i = 0
j = 0
while i < 4:
    sheet.col(i).width_mismatch = True
    sheet.col(i).width = 256*25
    i += 1
while j < 200:
    sheet.row(j).height_mismatch = True
    sheet.row(j).height = 896
    j += 1
```

This can just be

```
for i in range(4):
    sheet.col(i).width_mismatch = True
    sheet.col(i).width = 256*25
for j in range(200):
    sheet.row(j).height_mismatch = True
    sheet.row(j).height = 896
```

`csvfile_reader` should also use `with`:

```
# Temporary CSV file with device data
with open('inventory.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    for rowx, row in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile)):
        for colx, value in enumerate(row):
            sheet.write(rowx, colx, value, cell_style)
```

You write

```
global inventory_dir
inventory_dir = folder + 'Inventory\\'
```

which is then used by `embed_txt_files` and `rename_files`. Since you call these as

```
csv_to_xls()
embed_txt_files()
rename_file()
```

You could trivially remove the global by doing

```
inventory_dir = csv_to_xls()
embed_txt_files(inventory_dir)
rename_file(inventory_dir)
```

Globals variables are evil; they prevent you from reusing your functions (such as how now you couldn't do this in parallel on several directories) and make data flow hard to figure out. Don't use them.

I do find it odd that you're doing

```
inventory_dir = folder + 'Inventory\\'
```

where moments before you were using

```
os.path.join
```

but since you're using Windows-only APIs it's a bearable crime.

Do note that

```
if not os.path.exists(inventory_dir):
    os.makedirs(inventory_dir)
```

is prone to [TOCTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) race conditions. It's probably not especially worrisome here since your whole code is one big race condition of that kind, but you should be aware of the risks.

In `embed_txt_files` you write

```
range = wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200")
```

`range` is one of the most fundemental builtins; it's best not shadow it. You only use this once so I'd put it at point of use:

```
# First 200 cells in column A
for cell in wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200"):
```

With

```
xl.Visible = 0
```

you can probably do

```
xl.Visible = False
```

since `0 == False` in Python. I suggest doing so since it makes the action self-explanatory.

This could be better with formatting:

```
f = folder + str(cell.Value) + '.txt'
```

to

```
f = "%s%s.txt" % (folder, cell.Value)
```

or moving to new-style formatting (this would change your other format) with

```
f = "{}{}.txt".format(folder, cell.Value)
```

The name `f` should also be improved to, say, `filename`. Same with `ol` (I chose `ole_obj`).

Now in `rename_file`, remove dead comments like

```
# global xl_inventory_fname
```

You can simplify

```
print_new_section('What would you like to name your Inventory spreadsheet?')
inventory_fname = raw_input('\n\t:')
xl_inventory_fname = inventory_fname + '.xls'
```

to

```
print_new_section('What would you like to name your Inventory spreadsheet?')
x1_inventory_fname = raw_input('\n\t:')
xl_inventory_fname += '.xls'
```

although now the `raw_input` line is so short it might as well just be

```
print_new_section('What would you like to name your Inventory spreadsheet?')
x1_inventory_fname = raw_input('\n\t:') + '.xls'
```

I wouldn't wrap

```
os.rename(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls', inventory_dir + xl_inventory_fname)
```

The wrapping seems more intrusive than a line of length 87.

You can probably move most `print_new_section` calls into `main`; where possible a function shouldn't be dealing with both logic and UI. `rename_file` seems to be the exception, so keep that as-is.

You do `global folder` in `main`; just pass it in as parameters to your functions.

`main`'s docstring is now

```
"""
Open browser window to enable user to choose folder containing 
their 'show' text files.
"""
```

This seems misleading; the function does far more than that. It should be a comment above the code it's talking about, not the function.

Finally, you do

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Use a version specifier:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
```

This all gives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

'''
Title:      Show File Inventory Creation
Usage:      Creates an excel spreadsheet inventory from a folder containing 
            Cisco 'show version' text files.  This inventory contains the 
            hostname, model & serial number of each device, including switch 
            stacks, and embeds each text file in the spreadsheet.
Platform:   Windows
Warning:    Only works with .xls files, NOT with .xlsx files
            'show' files must be .txt files
Date:       06/01/2015
Version:    2.1
''' 

import csv
import os
import re
import win32com.client as win32
import win32gui
import xlwt

from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon
from xlwt import Workbook, easyxf

# Define global variables for excel spreadsheet workbook and worksheet
book = Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet('Inventory', cell_overwrite_ok=True)

def print_new_section(text):
    print('\n\n' + ('=' * 100) + '\n\n\t' + text)

def read_showfile_into(showfile, inventorytxt):
    for line in showfile:
        # Hostname precedes 'show version' command
        if re.search(r'# sh(ow?)? ver', line):
            hostname = line.split('# ')[0]
            inventorytxt.write(hostname)

        # Model is last entry
        if 'Model number' in line:
            model = line.split()[-1]
            inventorytxt.write(',' + model + ',')

        # Serial number is last entry
        if 'System serial number' in line:
            serial = line.split()[-1]
            inventorytxt.write(serial + '\n')

def inventory_data_to_csvfile(path):
    """
    Parse show files and store data in csv format.

    Takes the path for the folder containing the show files.
    """
    # Temporary file for device data. 'a' :- append
    with open('inventory.txt', 'a') as inventorytxt:
        inventorytxt.write('Hostname,Model,Serial Number\n')

        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as showfile:
                read_showfile_into(showfile, inventorytxt)

    os.rename('inventory.txt', 'inventory.csv')

def csv_to_xls(folder):
    """Write csv data to Excel spreadsheet."""

    header_style = xlwt.easyxf(
        'font: name Calibri, bold on, height 320, colour white;'
        'borders: left medium, right medium, top medium, bottom medium;'
        'alignment: horizontal centre, vertical centre;'
        'pattern: pattern solid, fore_colour black;'
        )
    cell_style = xlwt.easyxf(
        'font: name Calibri, bold off, height 240;'
        'borders: left medium, right medium, top medium, bottom medium;'
        'alignment: horizontal centre, vertical centre;'
        )

    for i in range(4):
        sheet.col(i).width_mismatch = True
        sheet.col(i).width = 256*25
    for j in range(200):
        sheet.row(j).height_mismatch = True
        sheet.row(j).height = 896

    # Freeze header row
    sheet.set_panes_frozen(True)
    sheet.set_horz_split_pos(1)

    # Temporary CSV file with device data
    with open('inventory.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
        for rowx, row in enumerate(csv.reader(csvfile)):
            for colx, value in enumerate(row):
                sheet.write(rowx, colx, value, cell_style)

    # Re-write header row with new style
    sheet.write(0, 0, 'Hostname', header_style)
    sheet.write(0, 1, 'Model', header_style)
    sheet.write(0, 2, 'Serial Number', header_style)
    sheet.write(0, 3, 'Show File', header_style)
    inventory_dir = folder + 'Inventory\\'
    if not os.path.exists(inventory_dir):
        os.makedirs(inventory_dir)
    # save spreadsheet as temporary .xls file
    book.save(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls')
    return inventory_dir

def embed_txt_files(folder, inventory_dir):
    """Embed text files in spreadsheet."""
    xl = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    xl.Visible = 0
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls')

    # First 200 cells in column A
    for cell in wb.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A200"):
        if cell.Value is not None:
            # Get 'show' text file from hostname in column A
            filename = "{}{}.txt".format(folder, cell.Value)
            # Embed as OLEObject 
            ole_obj = wb.ActiveSheet.OLEObjects().Add(Filename=filename)
            ole_obj.Top = cell.GetOffset(0, 3).Top
            ole_obj.Left = cell.GetOffset(0, 3).Left

    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save()
    xl.Quit()

def rename_file(inventory_dir):
    """Prompt user to rename the inventory spreadsheet."""

    print_new_section('What would you like to name your Inventory spreadsheet?')
    x1_inventory_fname = raw_input('\n\t:') + '.xls'
    # test validity of users filename and rename temporary .xls file to 
    # user's desired name if an exception is not raised
    try:
        os.rename(inventory_dir + 'INVENTORY.xls', inventory_dir + xl_inventory_fname)
        print_new_section(
            'Your Inventory spreadsheet has been created here: \n\n\t{}{}'
                .format(inventory_dir, xl_inventory_fname)
        )
        print_new_section('')
    except:
        print_new_section('Sorry, that is an invalid filename.')
        rename_file()

def main(): 
    # Open browser window to enable user to choose folder containing 
    # their 'show' text files.
    desktop_pidl = shell.SHGetFolderLocation (
        0, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP, 0, 0
        )
    pidl, display_name, image_list = shell.SHBrowseForFolder (
        win32gui.GetDesktopWindow (), desktop_pidl, 
        "Please choose the folder containing your 'show' files...", 
        0, None, None
        )

    # Choice made in browser window
    folder = shell.SHGetPathFromIDList (pidl) + '\\'

    print_new_section("Retrieving device data from your 'show' files...")
    inventory_data_to_csvfile(folder)
    print_new_section('Saving device data to Excel spreadsheet...')
    inventory_dir = csv_to_xls(folder)
    print_new_section("Embedding your 'show' files into Excel spreadsheet...")
    embed_txt_files(folder, inventory_dir)
    rename_file(inventory_dir)
    # delete temporary csv file
    os.remove('inventory.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I haven't been able to test this so it's probably broken somewhere.

Comment: Thankyou very much @Veedrac for taking the time to do this.  I'm going to read and process this and make sure I understand what you've said.  Again thankyou, this kind of thing is invaluable! Rob